# Cannot get the value from dynamic table on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

On page load I am filling out table using json result. Below is my all code Table is filling up perfectly but though i cann the CalculatingOtherDetails after FillGridView it goes in controller with empty Amount() it doesnt contain any value. By putting break in console I find out that table is not filled out when function CalculatingOtherDetails() is called. How is it possible when i call FillGridView() function before CalculatingOtherDetails() it should get gridview values but it not

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           FillGridView();
           CalculatingOtherDetails();
        }
    });



function FillGridView() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("PopulateGridView", "ConsolidatedMedicineBill")",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { patient_no: document.getElementById("IPDNo").value},
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                $('#MedicineDetails tr').last().after('<tr>' +
                            '<td class="column"></td>' +
                            '<td class="column" nowrap data-label="Medicine Name">' + item.medicine_name +
                            '</td><td class="column" nowrap data-label="Batch No">' + item.batch_no +
                            '</td><td class="column" nowrap data-label="Expiry Dt">' + item.expiry_date +
                            '</td><td class="column" nowrap data-label="Rate">' + item.rate +
                            '</td><td class="column" nowrap data-label="Qty">' + item.qty +
                            '</td><td class="column" nowrap data-label="Free Qty">' + item.free_qty +
                            '</td><td class="column" nowrap data-label="UOM">' + item.unit +
                            '</td><td class="column" nowrap data-label="Amount">' + item.amount +
                            '</td></tr>');
            });
            //Your success message
        },
        error: function (result) {
            //alert("Error" + result);
            //Your error message
        }
        });
        CalculatingOtherDetails();

    }

    function CalculatingOtherDetails() {
        var Amount = new Array();
        $("table#MedicineDetails tr").each(function (row, tr) {
            Amount[row] = $(tr).find('td:eq(8)').text();
        });
        Amount.shift();
        console.log(Amount);
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("CalculateAmountItem", "ConsolidatedMedicineBill")",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ patient_no: document.getElementById("IPDNo").value, Amount: Amount }),
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                $('#ItemTotal').val(item.item_total);
                $('#AddLess').val(item.add_less);
                $('#SponsorAmt').val(item.sponsor_amount);
                $('#Total').val(item.total);
                $('#DepositAmt').val(item.deposit_amt);
                $('#PaidAmt').val(item.paid_amt);
            });
            //Your success message
        },
        error: function (result) {
            //alert("Error" + result);
            //Your error message
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: You are making an Ajax request that returns before the success call.  Call calculate from the success handler of the fill function.

Comment: Call it right where you have the comment // Your success message

Comment: Thank you @BJSafdie I realized that it was a silly mistake sorry to bother and It works perfectly

Comment: We all make those kinds of silly mistakes occasionally.  You were not a bother. I am glad I could help.